# Quick edit promoted links

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, promoted-links

Is there a way to edit quickly Promoted Links? Because editing item by item is quite long. I was thinking data sheet view but can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on All Promoted Links view and then Choose Edit.

This will bring up the Data Sheet View.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that trick. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to edit the "All Promoted Links" view.  I always modify that particular view to include the out-of-the-box "Edit" button.  It makes it quick and easy to access a promoted link item's edit form.